# How to determine type of result from function in Julia without performing the computation

Tags: types, julia

In Julia, is there a way to get the type of a function's return value given its arguments (or only the types of its arguments), without running the function?  For instance, I would like to do this:

```
function foo(a, b)
    RetType = typeof(f(a, b))
   
    # do something
end
```

The problem here is that I actually called `f` on `a` and `b` to get the return type.  Is there a way to avoid the function call?  Something along the lines of `promote_type` or related functions?

Comment: The compiler does this internally, see https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/devdocs/inference/ for more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the following function:

```
gettype(f, a, b) = last(@code_typed f(a, b))
```

Now you can do:

```
julia> gettype(+, 1, 2)
Int64

julia> gettype(+, 1, 2.)
Float64

julia> gettype(append!, Int[], 3)
Vector{Int64} (alias for Array{Int64, 1})
```